# Issue with Anaconda Python 3.5 script

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

Having an issue with a fresh install of Anaconda.  I created an environment with Python 3.5 and trying to run a simple script but for whatever reason I am seeing an issue during the import statements.

```
import os
import csv
import numpy as np
import scipy
```

So there are other reports of similar errors on SO but they are from awhile back and do not seem to be linked to Anaconda.  I have NOT seen this before on my laptop )running el capitan) also running miniconda (btw this is happening on a mac osx el capitan). I cannot understand why anaconda would try calling usr/local/lib/python2.7 while the environment is in python 3.5.  Is this normal?  Any assistance would be greatly appreciated!!!

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "myTest.py", line 11, in <module>
    import scipy
  File "/Users/dennis/anaconda/envs/test/lib/python3.5/site-packages/scipy/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from numpy import show_config as show_numpy_config
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py", line 180, in <module>
    from . import add_newdocs
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/add_newdocs.py", line 13, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/__init__.py", line 8, in <module>
    from .type_check import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/lib/type_check.py", line 11, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
    from . import multiarray
ImportError: dlopen(/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so, 2): Symbol not found: _PyBuffer_Type
  Referenced from: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
  Expected in: flat namespace
 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.so
```

Comment: Just a quick comment...I installed ipython notebook and tried a simple **import scipy** which yields the same error

Comment: Did you try opening a fresh terminal window? Not just a new tab.

Comment: Hi Mike, yes, at first I thought it might be a bug in Anaconda but I had the same issue with my miniconda install prior to scrapping that and installing the most recent anaconda release.  I am thinking this is an issue with something in my env (not anaconda env) but I have not a clue on what would cause this.

Answer (score 0):

Well after digging around and trying to solve this issue most of last night I could not come up with much.  I must have done something to my environment (I had done some builds of a couple of libraries from source)...anyway worst StackOverflow answer of all time, I used my TimeMachine to reset my mac back a week and the issue is gone.  I guess the lesson is even if you are using environments in anaconda backups still cannot be beat.